# Wordpress theme settings not saving

Tags: theme-development, settings-api

I am trying to develop a theme. I am at the part of using the settings API.
The code I use for the settings are as follows:

**In the example snippets I'm using variables to show the structure of my code.
Ofcourse in my actual code the variables are strings (the callback variables are no strings)**

```
register_setting($option_group, $options_name);
add_settings_section($id, $title, $callback_section, $page);
add_settings_field($id, $title, $callback_field, $page, $section);

function $callback_section()
{
}

function $callback_field()
{
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="$option_name" />';
}
```

for the form in my theme options page:

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">

    <?php
          settings_fields($option_group);
          do_settings_sections($page);
          submit_button();
          settings_errors();
    ?>

</form>
```

My settings are saved but the input returns to the unchecked state. How can I make it work? Did I miss anything?
Also.. I will need alot of settings. What is the best approach for handling alot of settings with the settings API without getting messy code?

Answer (score 0):

```
$options = get_option( 'textdomain_settings' );
    ?>    
<input type='checkbox' name='textdomain_settings[textdomain_checkbox_field_0]' <?php checked( $options['textdomain_checkbox_field_0'], 1 ); ?> value='1'>
<?php
```

Use this settings under **Callback Field Function** or you can generate code form [here](http://wpsettingsapi.jeroensormani.com/) for settings api directly.